# Typeorm order by after distinct on with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, distinct, typeorm, distinct-on

I have a table below:

| id | product_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | 150 |
| 3 | 2 | 120 |
| 4 | 2 | 190 |
| 5 | 3 | 100 |
| 6 | 3 | 80 |

I want to select cheapest price for product and sort them by price

Expected output:

| id | product_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 3 | 80 |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 3 | 2 | 120 |

What I try so far:

```
`
 repository.createQueryBuilder('products')
.orderBy('products.id')
.distinctOn(['products.id'])
.addOrderBy('price')
`
```

This query returns, cheapest products but not sort them. So, `addOrderBy` doesn't effect to products. Is there a way to sort products after `distinctOn` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id,
       product_id,
       price
FROM   (SELECT id,
               product_id,
               price,
               Dense_rank()
                 OVER (
                   partition BY product_id
                   ORDER BY price ASC) dr
        FROM   product) inline_view
WHERE  dr = 1
ORDER  BY price ASC;
```

Setup:

```
postgres=# create table product(id int, product_id int, price int);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into product values (1,1,100),(2,1,150),(3,2,120),(4,2,190),(5,3,100),(6,3,80);
INSERT 0 6
```

Output

```
id | product_id | price
----+------------+-------
  6 |          3 |    80
  1 |          1 |   100
  3 |          2 |   120
(3 rows)
```